# ActivityIndicator color property not working in windows 8.1

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to change the color of Activity Indicator in windows 8.1 ?

The Color property seems to get ignored in Xamarin Forms 2.0.0.0 stable.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Forms source code](https://github.com/jimmgarrido/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/ActivityIndicatorRenderer.cs#L59), the native control's Foreground property is being used to set the color. Searching online, it turns out that this just [doesn't work on Windows 8.1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/957b333f-035f-448e-9f4a-213d1290ee51/indeterminate-progressbar-foreground-dosent-work?forum=winappswithcsharp).

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/479) to fix this, but in the mean time the simplest way to do this would be to override the brush in the Windows 8.1 App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```